# Using hawtio to host multiple applicatoins

Tags: hawtio

Is it recommended to use hawtio as a host for several small user interfaces? What we have are a lot of discreet services performing fairly focused tasks each with it's own (angularjs) UI for configuration and management. A thought I had was that we might deploy each of these UIs so that they could be incorporated into hawtio where they would live on individual tabs.

Additionally we would want to have some kind of authentication/authorization to limit which tabs users could see. For example we would not want everyone to see the JBoss or Camel tabs but we would want them to see the UIs that we created for the individual services (and probably levels of authorization within them).

Is this even a reasonable use for hawtio?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your custom distribution of hawtio, or turn off various plugins etc by providing a html file where you can turn off them in the various perspectives.

There is some examples how to do that at

- https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-plugin-examples/custom-perspective

You can build 3rd party plugins for your own apps and have them integrated as first-class in hawtio.

hawtio is designed as a pluggable web console.